# MYSQL Replication - in some scenarios not replicating

Tags: mysql, centos, replication

I have set up a basic mySQL replication across two Centos servers, lets call them Server1 and Server2.

It works fine. If I log into mySQL command line via root on Server1 and insert into a table, I can see the insert on Server2 database.

The SHOW SLAVE STATUS and SHOW MASTER status are all in sync and it looks healthy.

However, if I connect to Server1 from my desktop using MySQL workbench (different user, but one that has insert access) and enter anything, I can still see it on Server1 (from command line, on root) but I cannot see it on Server2.

No errors, no nothing.

Hope you can help, this is driving me mad.

Comment: Sorry away from my desk for the mo. Latest mysql, set up using mysql dump, don't know about format (something for me to look into?, any tips?). Will get back on the other questions.

Comment: Database called lll, on the master it says : mysql-bin.000001 |      743 | lll

Comment: On Slave the status is :  Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000001
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 743

Comment: So I have just done another insert to check - again, it has appeared OK in the MASTER, but not in the slave. I have checked the status of both and they are in sync

Comment: Just checked the versions - on the MASTER it is version 5.1.73 x86_64 redhat-linux-gnu, on the SLAVE it is 5.6.27 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Comment: Going to put the same version on both and see if it still happens. Will get back soon.

Comment: No difference, still got the same problem. Both versions of MySQL now at 5.6.27. Replication looks like it is healthy, both SLAVE and MASTER reporting the same Master_Log_File and the same Read_Master_Log_Pos, both Slave IO and Slave SQL running. No errors. Created a new table which can be seen in both, but then populated data with a user that is not root, from my desktop - data appears in MASTER but cannot be seen in SLAVE.

Answer (score 0):

It is  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27831400/mysql-queries-from-the-mysql-workbench-wont-replicate)

It is MySQL Workbench, the SQL scripts from there did not state 'use '.

This is affected by the setting in the my.cnf, it is the **replicate-do-db** setting :

[More details here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-options-slave.html)